# Parse the css content in C#

Tags: c#, css, xamarin

I am using [ExCSS.dll](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExCSS/) to parse the web CSS and used in my xamarin mobile project. Previously, there is only one CSS file at web and all the content parsed successfully. But now there is four css at web and I need to parse all content.

For this at web, we make a single WCF method that read all four css file content and return by concat all four as result. **When we try to parse ExCSS.dll whole content not parsed.** It gives old content and skip major new contents.

Please help me in this situation.